# JFrame custom component not showing up

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a problem with my TicTacToe Game. I made 2 custom components, one for the tictactoe board and one for the stats. The board shows up but the stats stay hidden... Why?

Main Method:

```
public Game() {
    player1 = new Player("Tester1", PieceType.Cross, Color.RED);
    player2 = new Player("Tester2", PieceType.Circle, Color.BLUE);
    currentPlayer = random.nextInt(2);

    board = new TicTacToeBoard(125, 125, 3, 3);
    stats = new Stats(375, 0, 376, 125);

    setTitle("Tic Tac Toe");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    add(board);
    add(stats);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Stats class (the necessary part):

```
    /**
 * @param x
 * @param y
 * @param width
 * @param height
 */
public Stats(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(x, y, width - 1, height - 1);
}
```

That code should draw 2 boxes, right? It only draws the green one...
The Minmal, Complete and Verifiable Example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test {

    public test() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Test");
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.add(new a(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(new b(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);  

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class a extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 100);
        }

    }

    class b extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            g.fillRect(0, 100, 200, 100);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: You need to show more, a [mcve] would be best. Problem: you're overriding paint method (something that shouldn't be done), and not calling the `super.paint(...)` method within the override. Question: Does the Stats class have a `getX()` and `getY()` method? If so rename those immediately.

Comment: I have renamed the getX and getY methods, it still doesn't work. Can you explain why I should rename those and why I shouldn't override the paint method?

Comment: getX and getY are used by layout managers to position components, and if you override them without understanding what the super methods do, you can cause components to not appear or to appear in strange locations. As for paint, that is responsible for painting components, child components and borders, and if done incorrectly you mess up not only painting of the component but the other issues as well. You should override a JPanel's paintComponent method and call the super's method so that house keeping painting can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
add(board);
add(stats);
```

The default layout for a JFrame is a BorderLayout. You don't specify where in the BorderLayout you want the components to go so it defaults to the CENTER. However you can only have a single component in the CENTER.

Try:

```
add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
add(stats, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent(...) method, not the paint() method. And you need to invoke super.paintComponent(...) as the first statement.

When you do custom painting you also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method so the layout manager can do their job properly. Otherwise the size of your components will be (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Save this link to the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).

You will find sections on:

1. `How to Use BorderLayout`
2. `Performing Custom Painting`

The tutorial has working example of all the Swing basics. Start by downloading those demo programs.

Comment: JFrame does not have a paintComponent() mehod.

Comment: @FredK, I know. The `Stats` class is not a JFrame. You can't add a JFrame to a JFrame. In any case you should NOT be doing custom painting on a JFrame. Read the tutorial.

Comment: Exactly. But for some reason a lot of posts to SO are done by people who haven't been taught that it is almost always a bad idea to subclass JFrame. Also,(for @Nicolas): you didn't include the necessary part - a critical part was the declaration of your classes and what they subclass.